# Using multple geom_text with custom coordinates in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to add custom text to a predefined location into my ggplot.
I've searched at various places and I think I almost got it, but something in my code is not making it work properly.
Here is the sample data:

```
x <- data.frame(Snapshot_Date = c(
  "2016-12-31",
  "2016-12-31",
  "2016-12-31",
  "2016-12-31",
  "2017-12-31",
  "2017-12-31",
  "2017-12-31",
  "2017-12-31"),
           NewExisting = c('Existing',
                      'Existing',
                      'New',
                      'New',
                      'Existing',
                      'Existing',
                      'New',
                      'New'
                      ),
           Product = c( 'CC',
                        'ETA',
                        'CC',
                        'ETA',
                        'CC',
                        'ETA',
                        'CC',
                        'ETA'
                      ),
           prop = c(0.2384310,
                    0.4268317,
                    0.2099592,
                    0.4991919,
                    0.2201962,
                    0.4729444,
                    0.1375661,
                    0.5504558)
    ,stringsAsFactors = F)
x$Snapshot_Date <- as.factor(x$Snapshot_Date)
x$NewExisting <- as.factor(x$NewExisting)
```

I have created a seperate `df` for the corrdinates, as recommended by various sites:

```
facet_group <- data.frame(NewExisting = c("Existing","New")) # order matters
lable.coord <- data.frame(
  x=c(-Inf,-Inf),y = c(Inf,Inf),
  facet_group,
  labs = c("lab1","label2"),
  hjust1 = c(0,0),
  vjust1 = c(1,1))
```

Now when I plot the graph I get an error:`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Snapshot_Date' not found`

```
ggplot(x,aes(x = Product, y = prop, fill = Snapshot_Date)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~NewExisting, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(prop)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = -.5,
            cex = 4,
            colour = "black"
  )+ # works upto here
  geom_text(data = lable.coord, aes(
    x = x, y = y,
    label = labs,
    group = NULL,
    vjust = vjust1,
    hjust = hjust1
  ))
```

The code appears to work upto just before the second use of `geom_text()`. It seems that using a different dataset is causing the problem.

If I adjust the code and move the `fill = Snapshot_date` to the `geom_col()` instead, then the graphs plots. But now it seems to ignore the `position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)` argument.

```
ggplot(x,aes(x = Product, y = prop)) +
  geom_col(aes( fill = Snapshot_Date),position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~NewExisting, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(prop)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = -.5,
            cex = 4,
            colour = "black"
  )+
  geom_text(data = lable.coord, aes(
    x = x, y = y,
    label = labs,
    group = NULL,
    vjust = vjust1,
    hjust = hjust1
  ))
```

[image]

How do I keep the custom text in the corners and get it to show labels over the bars?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add `group=Snapshot_date` in your `geom_text` `aes`:

```
ggplot(x,aes(x = Product, y = prop)) +
  geom_col(aes( fill = Snapshot_Date),position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_wrap(~NewExisting, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
  geom_text(aes(label = prop, group=Snapshot_Date),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = -.5,
            cex = 4,
            colour = "black"
  ) +
  geom_text(data = lable.coord, aes(
    x = x, y = y,
    label = labs,
    group = NULL,
    vjust = vjust1,
    hjust = hjust1
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: the custom labels are missing in your output.

Comment: just add the additional call to `geom_text()` - see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realised what was missing that `Snapshot_Date` in the `label.coord` `df`. You need to make sure that you have all the factors in that `df` that are used in the graph.
When it gave me an error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Snapshot_Date' not found`
I assumed it was talking about the `x df`, the source data. But in fact it was referring to the `label.coord` `df`.

Here is the final working code:

```
facet_group <- data.frame(NewExisting = c("Existing","New"), Snapshot_Date = c('2016-12-31','2017-12-31')) 
lable.coord <- data.frame(
  x=c(-Inf,-Inf),y = c(Inf,Inf),
  facet_group,
  labs = c("lab1","label2"),
  hjust1 = c(0,0),
  vjust1 = c(1,1))


ggplot(x,aes(x = Product, y = prop,fill = Snapshot_Date)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~NewExisting, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(prop)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = -.5,
            cex = 4,
            colour = "black"
  )+
  geom_text(data = lable.coord, aes(
    x = x, y = y,
    label = labs,
    group = NULL,
    vjust = vjust1,
    hjust = hjust1
  ),position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[image]